# Why is `mlflow artifacts download` so much slower than `aws s3 cp`

Tags: amazon-s3, mlflow

I am using mlflow version 1.23.1

I have 1 large-ish file (~100MB) I have uploaded to s3 using 2 different methods: mlflow and directly through s3. Then I try pulling that file from the command line using 2 different commands:

```
time aws s3 cp s3://my-bucket/my_file.pth
```

**real  0m2.113s**
user    0m1.252s
sys 0m0.373s

versus

```
time mlflow artifacts download --artifact-uri dbfs:/databricks/mlflow-tracking/.../my_file.pth
```

**real  0m4.270s**
user    0m1.731s
sys 0m1.031s

Why does mlflow take so much longer, and is there anything I can do to speed it up? A couple of things I've found are

1. An [mlflow issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/issues/4668) resolved in Dec 2021 that said S3 artifact downloading is slow due to multiple client verifications
2. An mlflow issue](https://github.com/mlflow/mlflow/pull/5359) resolved in Feb 2022 that says file downloading is sped up using parallelization.